# How to setup port forwarding for HTTP

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I have a D-Link router and added a Virtual Server (Port Forward) on port 80.
My web server (apache) is running on 192.168.0.199
I have reserved this as my static IP address for this machine on the network.

I have an external static IP address, when I navigate to this address it shows me the login page of my modem. When I access it externally it gives HTTP Error 400.

[image: router page]

Comment: You have tried to go to your external.ip.address:80?

Comment: Yes, but still no luck.

Comment: It could be your ISP is blocking external requests on port 80. Many ISPs do that. Try changing the external port to something completely different, like 3555 or whatever, and see if that works.

Comment: First, your router's configuration shouldn't be externally visible.  Fix that.  Second, it might ignore forwarding port 80 because it's catching it itself for the configuration page.

Answer (score 0):

You have tested it internally right? Like you try connecting to http://192.168.0.199 and it works?

Somethin else to double check. I have seen before that some website when you log in over http auto redirect to https. As you may know this is a different port (443). If this is happening you get an error 400 bad request if the port isn't opern. It is easy to miss as well with it changing just one letter (S). Check that or if anything else is changing in the URL. If so port forward https as well

Comment: it needed to be configured on my modem as well as on the router.

Comment: Oh right. You never mentioned you had a modem as well...Or to be more exact a modem/router.